# Updated guide to install windows 11 in Ubuntu using LXD?

Tags: windows, 22.04, virtualization, lxc, lxd

I have been trying to install Windows 11 inside Ubuntu 22.04 via LXD without success. Several steps outlined in the guide [How to install a Windows 11 VM using LXD](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-a-windows-11-vm-using-lxd#1-overview) fail or don't work as presented. For example, I got errors in the command

```
lxc init win11 - -vm - -empty
```

with unknown parameter `m` or `-empty` which after investigating / googling I changed to

```
lxc init win11 - -v - --empty
```

I then finally got stuck in the command:

```
lxc start win11 --console=vga
```

which outputs the error:

```
Error: Failed to handle idmapped storage: No such file or directory: "/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/win11/rootfs"
Try `lxc info --show-log win11` for more info
```

and this suggesed command outputs:

```
Name: win11
Status: STOPPED
Type: container
Architecture: x86_64
Created: 2022/11/20 12:13 CET

Log:
```

Comment: First command options are likely --vm --empty.

Comment: I agree with @OrganicMarble.  Looking at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-install-a-windows-11-vm-using-lxd/28940/5 and after logging in, I can see someone stated on Jul 19 that the command is wrong and needs to be what Organic Marble says.